# JMeter - Add Client side Certificate and key

Tags: jmeter, ssl-certificate

How can we add a client-side certificate and key to JMeter Script?

Every time I'm navigating to `JMeter -> Options -> SSL Manager` and browsing the Certificate and entering the password then it's only allowing me to run the script successfully, else I'm getting the **forbidden error access denied**.

I have tried the below steps, but still facing the same issue:

1. Added below lines in **JMeter properties**:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12    
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\certs\mycert.p12
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
```

2. Tried using the **JSR223 Sampler** in JMeter script but still no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Forget about *jmeter.properties* file, any customization of [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html) should be done in *user.properties* file or in a separate copy of jmeter.properties which needs to be passed to JMeter via [`-p` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
2. In your case you're trying to change [**System Properties**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) so you need to put these lines to *system.properties* file
3. JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates)